# How may I remove "1.#QNAN" and "INF" error in gradient (float type) with image in case of inf or 0?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

In code to extract text from an image (Stroke Width Transform), I am using gradients at specific pixels.
In the following code:
`gradientX`, `gradientY` are Mat images. `G_x` and `G_y` are gradients at (row, col) pixel. I am getting the error because `G_x` and `G_y` are becoming out of bounds (1.#QNAN 1.INF) in many cases. In some cases, both become such that mag becomes INF or 1.#QNAN . 
Could someone please suggest some change to my code such that this problem can be mitigated?
I would like to normalize them to 1 in case of INF and make changes similarly.

```
            float G_x = gradientX.ptr<float>(row)[col];
            float G_y = gradientY.ptr<float>(row)[col];
            // normalize gradient
            double mag =  sqrt( (G_x * G_x) + (G_y * G_y) );
            if (dark_on_light){
                G_x = -G_x/mag;
                G_y = -G_y/mag;
            } else {
                G_x = G_x/mag;
                G_y = G_y/mag;

            }
```

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga62286befb7cde3568ff8c7d14d5079da

Comment: Hi sorry for the edit above . But that is a float actually.  Can u suggest something for that?

Comment: if(mag==0) dont divide by it

Comment: if(abs(mag) <someEpsilon) dont divide by it

Comment: The main problem is when (float type) mag/G_y/G_x is exceeding the limit. What should I do in such  a case??

Comment: Is there any way I can find out if a number is INF? Then in that case I'll alter the code accordingly.